# Is it possible to formulate an OPTIONAL "subquery" so that it returns at most one record

Tags: sparql, wikidata

The following Wikidata query returns a list of airports and their IATA codes.

I am using `?airport rdfs:label ?airportName` to also get a label for the airports. Most airports have labels in multiple languages, so I want to select preferably the english name. Some airports have only the language `en-ca` and `en-gb`, but not `en`, so I cannot select them with `lang(?airportName) = 'en'`.
With the current implementation, I get multiple records for some airports:

```
select
   ?airport
   ?airportName
  (lang(?airportName) as ?lang)
   ?IATAAirPortCode
{
   ?airport
    wdt:P238
   ?IATAAirPortCode
    optional {?airport rdfs:label ?airportName .
              filter(langMatches(lang(?airportName), 'en')) }
 }
 order by
    ?IATAAirPortCode
```

I'd like to have one record per airport only. Is it somehow possible to formulate an `optional { ... }` clause to return at most one record of an airport.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this style of query where you want a single `rdfs:label` value per result, you can use wikidata's `wikibase:label` SPARQL extension like this:

```
SELECT
   ?airport
   ?airportLabel
   (LANG(?airportLabel) AS ?lang)
   ?IATAAirPortCode
{
   ?airport wdt:P238 ?IATAAirPortCode
   SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en"
   }
}
ORDER BY ?IATAAirPortCode
```

The `?airportLabel` variable is automatically bound to the label of each `?airport` with only labels in the given preferred language (the language string `"en"` here can contain multiple, comma-separated acceptable language codes).

A more general-purpose solution that is portable SPARQL (without wikidata extensions) would be more complicated, and might differ depending on the specifics of the query. In this particular case, where your `OPTIONAL` is only adding one variable, you can do it without using the wikibase extension by using `GROUP BY` and `SAMPLE` aggregation:

```
SELECT
   ?airport
   (SAMPLE(?airportLabel) AS ?airportName)
   (LANG(?airportName) AS ?lang)
   ?IATAAirPortCode
{
   ?airport wdt:P238 ?IATAAirPortCode
   OPTIONAL {
     ?airport rdfs:label ?airportLabel
     FILTER(langMatches(lang(?airportLabel), 'en'))
   }
}
GROUP BY ?airport ?IATAAirPortCode
ORDER BY ?IATAAirPortCode
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if the wikibase:label extension has the same semantics as using `langMatches`. If you really want *any* English label, then you might need to enumerate language code variants like "en,en-ca,en-gb".